# How do I change the shape of UITextView in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, uitextview

Instead of having a normal text view, I want it to be another shape, for instance like the Text Field. The reason to why I am not using Text Field is because I want the text view to be uneditable.

Suggestions on how to change the shape?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean change the shape or change the size?

Comment: You could use a label.. they are uneditable.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying completely. I want some of them to be editable, and some of them not, but all of them to look the same.

Answer (score 1):

If what you really want to do is use a UITextField you have a few options:

1. textField.enabled = NO; // create an outlet to your text field and put this in ViewDidLoad to prevent editing but also selecting and copying
2. implement the delegate method: // this will allow copy/paste, etc. but no writing

   (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
       return NO; }

If you want to use a UITextView, the only shape items you can change are the width and height (you can't make it star shaped or anything). If you want rounded corners you could use QuartzCore as follows:

```
[textView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0]; // not needed but put here in case 
//Round the corners via a radius value`enter code here` (play with number to get what you want)
textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
textView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Note: UITextView gives you the added benefit of multi-lines and scrolling.

If you just want to display a value that can be read and copied then use a UILabel